# RXJava create an observable on completion of other

Tags: android, rxjs, rx-java

Hi I have been quite struggling with this for a while. Any help is appreciated.

I have a requirement to run one observable after completion of another observable. So e.g. The following code creates an observable from input value to value + 10.

```
 Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> getSequenceObservable(int value, int delay, int color) {
    return Observable.range(value,10)
            .map(i -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Value " + i
                        + " evaluating on " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " emitting item at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
                return new ColoredIntegerModel(i, color);
            });
}
```

The ColorIntegerModel is as follows

```
public class ColoredIntegerModel {

    private Integer mValue;
    private int mColor;

    public ColoredIntegerModel(Integer value, int color) {
        mValue = value;
        mColor = color;
    }

    public Integer getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }
}
```

I create the two observables as follows and concat them like so .

```
Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> observable1 = getSequenceObservable(1, 1000, Color.BLUE);

Observable<ColoredIntegerModel> observable11 = getSequenceObservable(11, 1000, Color.RED);

 mDisposable =
            observable1.concatWith(observable11)
            .doOnDispose(() -> {Log.d(TAG, "observable disposed");})
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .repeat(2)
            .subscribe((m) -> {
                Utils.appendColoredText(mResultTextView, "Adding item "
                        + m.getValue().toString() + "\n", m.getColor());
            });
```

The above code prints 1..10 (in blue each item delayed by 1s) and 11..20 (in red).

So far so good.

But my requirement is to create the second observable only after the first is complete. Infact it could be array of observables, where the n+1 observable is only created after the nth is done. Each observable can emit multiple items. Is there any operator to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood it right but if you want to create the `Observable` when you subscribe to it you need the [`defer`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html) operator

Comment: thanks i was looking for defer operator. it indirectly solves my issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can start next observable from doOnCompleted() of previous one

```
Observable<MyData> observable1 = ...;
Observable<MyData> observable2 = ...;
Observable<MyData> observable3 = ...;

Observable
       .concat(observable1.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable1),
            observable2.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable2),
            observable3.doOnCompleted(this::onCompleteObservable3))
            ...
            ...
```

Hope this help.